# How can I make it so that all dates in a UIDatePicker are the same color?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

By default, `UIDatePicker` displays today's date in a blue font and the rest of the dates in black.

How can I make it so that all the dates are black?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems `UIDatePicker` is not customizable via a delegate like `UIPickerView`. If you need this functionality, your best bet is probably to create your own custom date picker from a `UIPickerView`.